# Grep: Unknown syntax for entry (in 2 different machines: 1 machine's result is fine, another was error)

Tags: linux, ubuntu, grep, syntax-error

I have a question in grep only.

From this input:

> (pinkpink)(orangered)(bluegreen)(<(   )>)(<(
> )>)(purplegreen)(pinkblue)(pinkred)::George->Phil->
> (purplegreen)(pinkpink)(orangepurple)(redpurple)(redorange)(bluepurple)(<(    )>)(purpleorange)(greenorange)(redpurple)
> (greenpink)(orangeorange)(greenred)(redpink)(orangepink)(greenred)(<( )>)(blueorange)(orangepink)(pinkred)
> (orangered)(bluegreen)(purplegreen)(bluered)(bluegreen)(orangeorange)(<(
> )>)(<(    )>)(pinkred)(greengreen)(redblue)::George->Tom->(<( )>)(<(
> )>)(pinkblue)(purplered)(purplered)(redblue)(redgreen)(orangegreen)
> (redred)(purplepink)(pinkred)(<( )>)(pinkred)(redorange)(pinkgreen)(<(
> )>)(<( )>)::Phil->Edna->(<(

I have to make an output:

> ::George->Phil->
>
> ::George->Tom->
>
> ::Phil->Edna->

My command was:

```
grep -o -i '::\+[Harry|Edna|Phil|George|Tom]\+->\+[harry|edna|phil|george|tom]\+->'
FILE
```

It produced the output successfully in my machine, as you can see in the screenshot. I'm using Ubuntu 13.10.

[image: Success output]

However, my lecturer said that the command was **"Unknown syntax for entry."** in His machine. Where did I go wrong? How can I check my grep command is not "Unknown syntaxt for entry" in other machines for crosschecking? If different machines can produce different result, how and where can I produce reliable result for all kinds of linux and different hardware as possible?

Thank you very much.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using character classes incorrectly. The regex `[a|bc]` matches a single character which is one of the four listed characters: `a`, `|`, `b`, or `c`. You apparently want `(a|bc)` which matches either the literal string `a` or the literal string `bc`, but you need `grep -E` (aka `egrep`) for that.

Also, `::+` matches two or more colon signs, and `(a|bc)+` matches one or more sequences of either `a` or `bc`, i.e. something like `aaaa` or `abcabcbcbcaa`.

Comment: Yeah, my lecturer said that also. But, why my linux 13.10 produces the result correctly?! Do you have any idea? If the result was correct in my machine, I thought that there was nothing wrong in my command.

Comment: Random luck. The expression just happens to match the required input.

Comment: Haha, luck?! well. okay then. Thank you very much for your responses. :)